# Micronaut: k8s operator for all namespaces

Tags: micronaut, kubernetes-java-client, micronaut-kubernetes

I'm trying to create a Kubernetes Operator in Micronaut using `micronaut-kubernetes-operator` that listens to Pod events in all namespaces on my cluster.
However I can't get my code to work for any / all namespaces.

Listening to a defined namespace works with the following code:

```kotlin
@Operator(
  informer = Informer(
    apiType = V1Pod::class,
    apiListType = V1PodList::class,
    resourcePlural = "pods",
    namespace = "my_namespace"
  )
) //
class NetpolReconciler : ResourceReconciler<V1Pod> {

  override fun reconcile(
    request: Request,
    lister: OperatorResourceLister<V1Pod>,
  ): Result {
   ...
```

Setting `namespace` to `Informer#ALL_NAMESPACES` or `""` results in a NullPointerException when receiving a request:

```
09:30:43.942 [OperatorV1Pod-controller-12] [traceId:,spanId:] ERROR i.k.c.e.controller.DefaultController - Reconciler aborted unexpectedly
java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "io.kubernetes.client.informer.SharedIndexInformer.getIndexer()" because "sharedIndexInformer" is null
    at io.micronaut.kubernetes.client.operator.OperatorResourceLister.get(OperatorResourceLister.java:66)
    at operator.NetpolReconciler.reconcile(NetpolReconciler.kt:31)
    at io.micronaut.kubernetes.client.operator.controller.DefaultControllerBuilder.lambda$build$1(DefaultControllerBuilder.java:108)
    at io.kubernetes.client.extended.controller.DefaultController.worker(DefaultController.java:207)
    at io.kubernetes.client.extended.controller.DefaultController.lambda$run$1(DefaultController.java:154)
```

Can this even be achieved with `micronaut-kubernetes-operator`?

Comment: Did you try without resourcePlural and namespace like in the docs? https://micronaut-projects.github.io/micronaut-kubernetes/snapshot/guide/#kubernetes-operator